# How to call second redux hook after the first one completes

Tags: javascript, redux

Good day!
Can't make request, i don't know how to request information

```
const { id } = useParams();
const { data, isLoading } = jsonApi.useFetchStrategyQuery(id);

const { currentData } = catalogApi.useGetFundQuery(data.id)
```

Have the above hooks and question how call the hook on line 4 after the hook on line 2 completes.

useEffect() cannot be applied

First hook:

```
export const jsonApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'jsonApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: config.jsonUrl }),
  endpoints: build => ({
    fetchStrategy: build.query<IStrategy, string | number | undefined>({
      query: id => ({
        url: `/static/strategies/${id}.json`,
      }),
    }),
    fetchLegalEntity: build.query<LegalEntity, string>({
      query: name => ({
        url: `/static/legalEntities/${name}.json`,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

Second hook:

```
export const catalogApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'catalogApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl: config.infoApiUrl }),
  endpoints: build => ({
    getFund: build.query<Catalog[], string | number | undefined>({
      query: id => ({
        url: `/api/Products/${id}`,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
export const { useGetFundQuery } = catalogApi;
```

Comment: Is `useGetFundQuery` your own hook that you've created or is it something that's provided by an external library/package?

Comment: @NickParsons Both hooks are created by me. Hook code attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try and use a [`skipToken`](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage-with-typescript#skipping-queries-with-typescript-using-skiptoken) to skip your query when `data.id` doesn't have a value in it like so:

```js
import { skipToken } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react';
...
const { data, isLoading } = jsonApi.useFetchStrategyQuery(id);
const { currentData } = catalogApi.useGetFundQuery(data?.id ?? skipToken);
```

Above, if `data?.id` is `undefined` or `null`, `skipToken` is passed as an argument which tells redux to skip the query. Once your data has been fetched and `data.id` is defined, your query will re-run. You can see [this](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/conditional-fetching) part of the redux toolkit docs for more info on skips.